Drawer item focused on Tab press in React Native Expo
I'm building an app in React Native Expo (I'm new on this) and I'm struggling to highlight Drawer Navigation menu item when I press on Tab Navigation icon, I open the same screen in both situations. If I press on Drawer Navigation item the Tab Navigation icon is correctly highlighted when screen is opened, Tab Navigation is nested to Drawer Navigation. Some could help me if some solution exists?
Main Navigation file
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MainNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Main' screenOptions={{headerShown: false, animation:'none'}}>
            <Stack.Screen name='Main' component={DrawerNavigation}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default MainNavigation

Drawer Navigation file
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNavigation = () => {

    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Drawer.Screen 
                    name="dHome"
                    options={{
                        drawerLabel:({focused}) => {
                            return <Text style={{fontSize:16,marginLeft:-15, color:focused ? '#FE724C' : Colors.black,fontWeight:'600'}}>Home</Text>
                        },
                        headerShadowVisible:false,
                        drawerIcon:({focused}) => {
                            return <Ionicons name="home" size={24} color={focused ? '#FE724C' : '#D3D1D8'} />
                        }
                    }}
                    component={BottomTabNavigation}
                    initialParams={{screen:'Home'}}
                    
                />

                <Drawer.Screen 
                    name="dOrders"
                    options={{
                        drawerLabel:({focused}) => {
                            return <Text style={{fontSize:16,marginLeft:-15, color:focused ? '#FE724C' : Colors.black,fontWeight:'600'}}>Orders</Text>
                        },
                        headerShadowVisible:false,
                        drawerIcon:({focused}) => {
                            return <Ionicons name="reader" size={24} color={'#D3D1D8'} />
                        }
                    }}
                    component={BottomTabNavigation}
                    initialParams={{screen:'Orders'}}
                />


            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    )

}

export default DrawerNavigation

Bottom Tab Navigation file
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomTabNavigation = () => {  
      
    const setDrawerFocus =  useCallback((param) => {
        //I need to highlight menu voice
    });
   
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName='Home' screenOptions={{headerShown: false, animation:'none',tabBarShowLabel:false,tabBarStyle:{backgroundColor:'#ffffff', height: Platform.OS==="ios" ? 90 : 60}}}>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} 
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) =>{   
                        return <Ionicons name="home" size={26} color={focused ? '#FE724C' : '#D3D1D8' } />
                    },    
                }}
                listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                    tabPress: (e) => {
                        setDrawerFocus('Home');
                    },
                })}   
            />
            <Tab.Screen name="Orders" component={OrdersScreen} 
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) =>{   
                        return <Ionicons name="reader" size={26} color={focused ? '#FE724C' : '#D3D1D8' } />
                    },
                }}  
                listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                    tabPress: (e) => {
                        setDrawerFocus('Orders');                      
                    },
                })}        
            />
           
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}

export default BottomTabNavigation

